# Move ViewPort of a 360° video with PyQT5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I want to endlessly move the ViewPort of a 360° video from left to right.

Is it possible with PyQT5? I haven't found an example of this...

[EDIT:]
I want to show a small part of the 360° view (video), like moving your head.

For displaying I want to use QT (PyQT if possible).

I've never worked with it, hence my fairly general question. I hope someone can give me a few tips or example links.

As an an example:

I have a video that is 4096x768px and I want to display a 1024x768px portion of it while moving left to right across the video.

Comment: Sorry but your question is extremely vague. What viewport? How are you displaying the video? Please add more details, as right now your question is not answerable. Also, "is it possible" is not a question that really fits StackOverflow: we normally answer to *specific, detailed questions*, so if you tried without success, then show us your attempts.

Comment: I've updated my question, hope it is enough information for any help?

Comment: Sorry, but if you're asking for a tutorial or code examples, StackOverflow is not really the place, especially if you've not written anything yet. Asking about links and resources is also off-topic, so please take your time to check the [help/on-topic], read [ask] and review the [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Comment: I'm not looking for a tutorial. I've already searched the internet for tips, but haven't found any useful approach. That's why I reached out to the community here in hopes of getting help.

I'm sorry if that's not what you want here. If someone has an idea about the problem, I would be happy. If I have violated the rules with my question, please simply delete the question. :-(

Comment: It's not that "I don't want it here". Your question is too broad as it asks about a problem that could be specific only to the way you implement the core aspects of your program: you're practically asking how to make your car go faster but you still haven't choose what car you'll buy. In fact, it's like you've never driven a car (you've never worked with PyQt), and for what we know you could even decide to buy a bicycle. There are various ways to show video even in PyQt (directly from Qt's QMediaPlayer or with external libraries), and depending on it the solution can be *extremely* different.

Comment: If you're going to start comparing...

I'm not asking how I can make a car faster. I would like a car for a specific purpose and I would like a recommendation and possibly an explanation as to why that would be good.

But I can see that I probably have too high expectations and I'm probably wrong here. I'll just keep looking on my own and hope to get an impetus elsewhere.

Anyway, thank you for the time you've invested here...